# Flow of events in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy server. I know more of the configurations, its directives etc. But, lately when I was figuring out as to how Nginx works or processes our request. I couldn't find anything useful except that it first searches for a server block and within it, the most specific location block. 
Now, after searching for the appropriate location block; how does the transfer happens from Nginx to backend server. And how is the response received or processed by Nginx?

Comment: https://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: This is about proxy_pass. I wanted some overview on flow of request from proxy_pass to the application and then It's response to Nginx?

Comment: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html - I guess, that's what you need?

Comment: Or this article - https://www.nginx.com/blog/inside-nginx-how-we-designed-for-performance-scale/ - it clears how Nginx process model is organized.

Comment: It just speaks HTTP (or https, if you asked for that) to the backend. This is so simple that I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want to know?